# unable to delete all documents of a type in an index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I couldn't delete documents of a type in an index in elasticsearch by nest or curl command at all.

Index: **testndx**
Type: **product**

I tried these:

**Nest:**
esconn.DeleteByQuery("testndx", "product", del => del.Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query("*"))));

**Curl:**
curl -X DELETE http://192.168.3.2:9200/testndx/product/_query?q=*
or
curl -X DELETE http://192.168.3.2:9200/testndx/product/_query

I'm using .Net 4.6.1, Nest 2.1.1, ElasticSearch 2.3.0.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Documentation for NEST is available on the elastic site: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DeleteByQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-delete-by-query.html) was removed in Elasticsearch 2.0.

In Elasticsearch 2.x, you should do a [Scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) request to get all documents to delete and actually delete them with a bulk request.

Nest Scroll Api:https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/search/scroll.html

Nest Bulk delete:https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/bulk.html

Comment: Michael thank you for your response. Can you please provide example code? I couldnt find proper documentation about elasticsearch, especially about nest client. If you can, can you please suggest some links to study? Thank you.

Comment: I added links to the nest client document. Hopefully, it helps. ;)

Comment: OK. Now I can delete documents. Now I need to get all documents of a type in one query. I read that search command is optimized for small queries and people suggest to write a number which is above the number I guess there should be. Well in my case there is no limit I can imagine. So, I also read that large resultset queries should be asked with scroll command. I even read that all documents can be retrieved by scroll command but I couln't find how. So my next question is how can I get all documents of a type with Nest? Thank you.

Comment: DeleteByQuery is still available as a separate plugin - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugins-delete-by-query.html

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :-) @RussCam do you know why DeleteByQuery seperated as a plugin? Does it have bad performance?

Comment: @zokkan https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-delete-by-query.html